# Qt QLabel HTML font size fails badly

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qlabel

In my Qt application (uses Qt 4.7.0 from Ubuntu 10.10 Linux repository) i tried to use `Qt::RichText` QLabels using the following HTML:

```
    label_1->setText("<font size=64>size=64</font>");
    label_2->setText("<font color=red size=10>size=10</font>");
    label_3->setText("<font color=blue size=14>size=14</font>");
```

For some reason the font sizes are not set properly. All the widgets get the same font size, one that is larger than the default one but still the wrong one. The font size set for the first widget seems to influence the size that the following widgets will use. Setting only the color attribute leaves the label text in its standard size.

I also tried to reproduce this in the QtDesigner and the same problem happens there.

Setting the text format to `Qt::Richtext` does not have any effect. And using quotes around the HTML attribute values does not change anything either.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so [font size is supported](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/richtext-html-subset.html) but have you tried CSS-style `font-size:64pt`? CSS is better because the size has explicit units.